# Date format in the Stack Exchange API

Tags: timestamp, stackexchange-api

When I query Stack Overflow (using it's API) to get some data (questions/answers/etc) I get the following JSON response:

```
"down_vote_count": 0, 
  "last_activity_date": 1300830790, 
  "creation_date": 1300829790,
```

The `last_activity_date` is a 10 digit number corresponding to some date in 1970. when I test today's timestamp (in Java if it's important) I get a 13 digit number.

What is the format of the date timestamps in the responses I get? How do I translate it to regular Unix timestamp?

Thanks.

Comment: even m looking for an answer to that ..

Comment: I guess [this](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/dates) should help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is in the `"d M Y h:i"` format. so if you're using php you can do :

```
function sanitizeDate($date){
  return date('d M Y h:i', $date);
}

//and call it like
$testdate = 1344855907;
echo sanitizeDate($testdate);
```

Answer (score 1):

I know it is an old post but the `"last_activity_date": 1300830790` is actually a Unix timestamp, and it translates to Tuesday, March 22, 2011 9:53:10 PM
This site https://www.epochconverter.com/ has a quick converter and some code to do the translation.