# How do I retrieve the actual date from the StackOverflow API *creation_date* field?

Tags: c#, stackexchange-api

How do I retrieve the actual date from the StackOverflow API *creation_date* field?

The date depicted via [their API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/users-by-ids#order=desc&sort=reputation&ids=492701&filter=!*MxMX(D8o7K)Y9Zm&site=stackoverflow&run=true) is an integer:

```
"creation_date": 1288523078
```

However, I would like to convert the integer into an actual DateTime value.

I saw this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5570831/date-format-in-the-stack-exchange-api). But it's still not clear to me.

Comment: Im not surprised you're puzzled - I cant see a date in that at all

Comment: Possible duplicate of [StackExchange API - Deserialize Date in JSON Response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23380182/stackexchange-api-deserialize-date-in-json-response)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in [docs](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/dates):

> All dates in the API are in unix epoch time, which is the number of
>   seconds since midnight UTC January 1st, 1970

To convert to .NET date time, do this:

```
int apiDate = 1288523078;
// `date` is UTC date here, if you need it in local timezone
//  call ToLocalTime() at the end
var date = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc).AddSeconds(apiDate);
```